# What is the boundary action need for topological massive gravity (TMG)?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gravity, variational-principle, topological-field-theory, boundary-terms

For pure Einstein gravity with Dirichilet boundary conditions, Gibbons-Hawking-York boundary action is needed to make the variational principle well defined. I am considering the case for topological massive gravity (TMG) in 3d where there is an additional Chern-Simons action and want to know what is the additional boundary action needed.